# Tree view constancy being nested after every refresh

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, treeview

I am new to Angular (7) coming from a c# background. I am using asp.net core 2.2 and using the default template which comes with angular new angular project( home, counter, fetch-data). The tree view is bound and is coming from a controller.

I am expecting

```
> Europe
>>  England
>>>   Manchester
>>>   London
>>>>    London City
>>>>    Stratford
>>  Germany
```

however, i'm getting, every time i expand

```
>   Europe
>>    Europe
>>>      Europe
>>>>        Europe
```

and so on

my code (home page which shows as soon as ISS express is loaded)

```
<p>
Testing Componenets
<app-tree-view> </app-tree-view>
```

**tree-view.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let n of nodes">
    <span><input type="checkbox" [checked]="n.checked" (click)="n.toggle()" /></span>
    {{ n.name }}>
    <div *ngIf="n.expanded">
      <app-tree-view [nodes]="n.nodes"></app-tree-view>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**tree-view.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree-view',
  templateUrl: './tree-view.component.html'
})
export class TreeViewComponent {

  @Input() nodes: Array<Node>;

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.nodes = [];
    http.get<Node[]>(baseUrl + 'api/FunctionNodes/GetNodes').subscribe(result => {
      this.nodes = this.RecursiveMapNodes(result.map(x => new Node(x.id, x.name, x.nodes)));
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

  RecursiveMapNodes(nodes: Array<Node>): Array<Node> {
    var result = Array<Node>();
    for (let node of nodes) {
      var n = new Node(node.id, node.name, this.RecursiveMapNodes(node.nodes));
      result.push(n);
    }
    return result;
  }
}

export class Node {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  nodes: Array<Node>;
  checked: boolean;
  expanded: boolean;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, nodes: Array<Node>) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.nodes = nodes;
    this.checked = false;
    this.expanded = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }
  check() {
    let newState = !this.checked;
    this.checked = newState;
    this.checkRecursive(newState);
  }

  checkRecursive(state) {
    this.nodes.forEach(d => {
      d.checked = state;
      d.checkRecursive(state);
    })
  }

}
```

**FunctionNodesController.cs**

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class FunctionNodesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable<Node> GetNodes()
        {
            var node_1 = new Node() { Id = 1, Name = "Europe" };
            var node_1_1 = new Node() { Id = 2, Name = "England" };
            var node_1_1_1 = new Node() { Id = 3, Name = "Manchester" };
            var node_1_1_2 = new Node() { Id = 4, Name = "London" };
            var node_2_1_1 = new Node() { Id = 5, Name = "London City" };
            var node_2_1_2 = new Node() { Id = 6, Name = "Stratford" };
            var node_1_2 = new Node() { Id = 7, Name = "Germany" };

            node_1.Nodes.Add(node_1_1);
            node_1_1.Nodes.Add(node_1_1_1);
            node_1_1.Nodes.Add(node_1_1_2);
            node_1_1_2.Nodes.Add(node_2_1_1);
            node_1_1_2.Nodes.Add(node_2_1_2);
            node_1.Nodes.Add(node_1_2);
            return new List<Node>() { node_1 };
        }

        public class Node
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
            public Node()
            {
                Nodes = new List<Node>();
            }
        }
    }
```

**app.module.tss**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { MainWindowComponent } from './main-window/main-window.component';
import { TreeViewComponent } from './tree-view/tree-view.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    MainWindowComponent,
    TreeViewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: MainWindowComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you show us the result from the BE that is loaded inside of the `nodes` variable in `tree-view.component.html`

Comment: i don't know what a BE is

Comment: every time i click on the tree view to expand i get the following results when i print out the nodes array: Europe,
England,
Manchester,
London,
London City,
Stratford,
Germany

Comment: BE is for Back End, (sorry this was my bad)  i mean what is inside the nodes like structure for example : [{name: node1, children: [ {name: node_1-child}, children:[] ]}] , if possible can you create a stackblitz with mock of the response from the back end. I assume that the problem lies within the structure of the response that you receive from tour back end.

Comment: ok i'v been looking around and by the looks of it my **TreeViewComponent.ts** might be an issue. Anytime there's a click on the tree for it to expand it fetches the data again (starting at rootnode which is Europe) from the controller as the treeviewComponent is being re- instanced and the way @Input works is that it passes the result onto the next instance (from what i read online), so i will always Europe as it's re fetching the data again every time there is a change in the nodes (click). I'm wondering what the best approach would be to solve this. I will look at the Backend in the meantime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I have created a little demo that you can use as reference, for the problem that you are tackling, you can find it here at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-dvzee).

As im not very knowledgeable about the C# part, I have created a mock back-end service that is supposed to act as your back-end.

About the question, why does it not work, as you had already mentioned in the comments, every time you are initializing (going a level in) your `tree-view.component.ts` inside of it's constructor you are fetching the data, which results in always getting 'Europe' displayed as result.

When creating recursive elements (trees and etc.) you must always provide to the recursive component (in your case `tree-view.component.ts`) the next layer of the tree.

For example first 'Europe' => ['England' => ['Manchester' , 'London' => ['London city', 'Stratford] ] , 'Germany'] , where each `=>` is building new `tree-view.component.ts`

```js
// Template
<div [ngStyle]="{'margin-left':level*12 +'px'}" *ngFor="let node of nodes">
  <h1>Current node = {{node?.name}}</h1>
  <div
    (click)="open=!open"
    style="cursor: pointer;"
    *ngIf="node?.nodes?.length!==0"
  >
    Expand nodes
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="open">
    <app-tree [level]="level+1" [nodesForDisplay]="node.nodes"></app-tree>
  </div>
</div>
// Component
@Component({
  selector: "app-tree",
  templateUrl: "./tree.component.html"
})
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input("nodesForDisplay") nodes;
  @Input("level") level = 0;
  open = false;
}
```

So in order to escape this deadlock, of always fetching the first layer, you can try creating a wrapper parent component, that handles the fetching and passes the data to the recursive components.

Another tip, is to remove the http call from the component and place it in a dedicated service, that you will inject inside of the components where needed (as done in the example)

```js
// Template
<app-tree [nodesForDisplay]="{{place to strore the data}}"></app-tree>

// Component
@Component({
  selector: "app-container",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class ContainerComponent {
  ...
  constructor(public fetcher: {{Your Service}}) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  this.fetcher.{{method to fethc the data}}.subscribe(x =>{
  this.{{place to strore the data}} = x
  })
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, your explanation of how components work helped me understand when it comes to recursion. I left **tree-view.ts** with just the @Inputs and in the main windows i used the tags and passed the data <app-tree-view [nodesForDisplay]="nodes"> </app-tree-view>

Answer (score 0):

i'm posting the code of the question and how it changed from the first post (FunctionNodesController.cs remains the same as original post), i don't know the best practices when it comes to angular so if you see something bad please leave a comment. (FunctionNodesController for this case can be renamed to RegionNodesController and similarly for FunctionService to RegionService)

**tree-view.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input,  } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode } from '../../classes/TreeNode';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree-view',
  templateUrl: './tree-view.component.html'
})
export class TreeViewComponent{

  @Input() nodes: Array<TreeNode>;
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

**tree-view.component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="nodes">
  <li *ngFor="let n of nodes">
    <span><input type="checkbox" (click)="n.toggle()" /></span>
    {{ n.name }}
    <div *ngIf="n.expanded">
      <app-tree-view  [nodes]="n.nodes"></app-tree-view>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**main-window.html**

```
<app-tree-view [nodes]="nodes"> </app-tree-view>
```

**main-window.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TreeNode } from '../../classes/TreeNode';
import { FunctionService } from '../../services/functionService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-window',
  templateUrl: './main-window.component.html',
})
export class MainWindowComponent{
  nodes = [];

  constructor(private funcService: FunctionService) {
    funcService.getNodeData().subscribe(result => {
      this.nodes = this.RecursiveMapNodes(result.map(x => new TreeNode(x.id, x.name, x.nodes)));
    }, error => console.error(error));

  }
    <!--this is required as during serialisation the methods/ function in nodes are not instanced unless we create a new object-->
  RecursiveMapNodes(nodes: Array<TreeNode>): Array<TreeNode> {
    var result = Array<TreeNode>();
    for (let node of nodes) {
      var n = new TreeNode(node.id, node.name, this.RecursiveMapNodes(node.nodes));
      result.push(n);
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

**TreeNode.ts (i renamed Node to treeNode)**

```
export class TreeNode {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  nodes: Array<TreeNode>;
  checked: boolean;
  expanded: boolean;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, nodes: Array<TreeNode>) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.nodes = nodes;
    this.checked = false;
    this.expanded = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }
  check() {
    let newState = !this.checked;
    this.checked = newState;
    this.checkRecursive(newState);
  }

  checkRecursive(state) {
    this.nodes.forEach(d => {
      d.checked = state;
      d.checkRecursive(state);
    })
  }
}
```

**functionService.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TreeNode } from '../classes/TreeNode';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class FunctionService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) { }

  getNodeData(): Observable<Array<TreeNode>> {
    return this.http.get<TreeNode[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/FunctionNodes/GetNodes');
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { MainWindowComponent } from './components/main-window/main-window.component';
import { TreeViewComponent } from './components/tree-view/tree-view.component';
import { FunctionService } from './services/functionService';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    MainWindowComponent,
    TreeViewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: MainWindowComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [FunctionService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```